# Magento 2 update inventory programmatically using cron

Tags: magento2, database, cron, inventory

I want to update the product inventory. Get inventory from another platform using cron once got inventory need to update in Magento but what is the best way to update some time I will get more than 200 items. can anyone please guide what is the best way to proceed

Comment: you have to try with Magento 2 rest API. that is the best way to import and update in Magento

Comment: you have to follow `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235334/magento2-api-stock-update` and also follow `https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-Rest-Api-to-Update-Stock/td-p/49249`

Comment: rest is ok but i want run every 30 min get inventory from some url (like crm) how we can use rest.one time cron run get 100 items if i update 100 iterations system will get more load so i want load more on system